# Move files from different users

Tags: bash, sh

I have a folder with some subdirs {users} e.g. "Michael", "Jackson" etc. pp. with other subdirs in each userdir: `cur`, `new` and `tmp`, these are Maildirs.

I need a script, that can move all Files/Mail from `new` to `cur` from each user.

How do I start to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your current directory is the directory containing all the users, you can do this:

```
for user in *; do mv "$user"/new/* "$user"/cur/.;done
```

Comment: hmm shouldn't that be `do mv "${user}/new/*" "${user}/cur/."`?

Comment: @izomorphius: That would work too.  The braces are unnecessary with a simple variable name.  Only the part of the string that might contain spaces needs to be quoted.

Comment: @izomorphius: Actually, the `*` needs to be outside the quotes in your code or else it won't expand.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks everybody. But the problem is the "USER" dir didn´t exists -> There are usernames as foldernames. i.e. "Michael" or "Jackson"

Comment: @user1747305: A folder and a directory are the same thing, so I don't understand your comment.